# ember.js: how do nested resources correspond to templates?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

given this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NYAm/3) ( I couldn't make it work, i'm sorry and very frustrated): i don't understand why, when i ask for a book detail, ember is asking not asking my `books/book`, but my `book` template. Is that a feature or i'm doing anything wrong?

And, in addition, when i structure my files tree correctly, asking for book detail gives:

-at 1st try: OUTPU: `OUTER`

-at 2nd try: OUTPUT: `Uncaught You can't call renderToBufferIfNeeded on a destroyed view`

and i really can't understand why

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, of all, here is a working version of your fiddle with latest ember.js and ember-data: http://jsfiddle.net/va9gc/

The reason why ember is looking for `book` template instead of `books/book` is because you define `book` as a resource, not as a `route`. This is explained here: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources